# Completablefuture doesnot complete on exception

Tags: java, completable-future, concurrent.futures

I'm kinda new to using CompletableFuture API and I have a question regarding usage of `allOf`. From what I read, completable-future should be in complete state and `allOf` logic should be executed when all associated futures complete, including `completed-exceptionally`. But here's my smaple code for which `allOf` block never gets executed -

```
public static void test() {
    CompletableFuture<String> r1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            throw new RuntimeException("blahh !!!");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });

    CompletableFuture<String> r2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "55");
    CompletableFuture<String> r3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "56");
    CompletableFuture.allOf(r1, r2, r3).thenRun(() -> { System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" --- End."); });
    Stream.of(r1, r2, r3).forEach(System.out::println);


    try{
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" --- SLEEPING !!!");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" --- DONE !!!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Stream.of(r1, r2, r3).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not that your `allOf` `CompletableFuture` never completes. It does.

What causes your code not to run is `thenRun`'s expectation:

> Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes **normally**, executes the given action. See the CompletionStage documentation for rules covering exceptional completion.

You probably already know that when one of `allOf`'s futures completes exceptionally, the resulting future also completes exceptionally:

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when all of the given CompletableFutures complete. If any of the given CompletableFutures complete exceptionally, then the returned CompletableFuture also does so, with a CompletionException holding this exception as its cause.

In short, don't use `thenRun` if you want to run an action on your `allOf` future irrespective of how it comples. As an alternative, you can use `whenComplete`:

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(r1, r2, r3)
        .whenComplete((a, ex) -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " --- End."));
```

You can also use a combination of `thenRun` + `exceptionally`, one of which will run:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> all = CompletableFuture.allOf(r1, r2, r3);
all.thenRun(() -> {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " --- End.");
});
all.exceptionally(ex -> {
    System.out.println(ex);
    return null;
});
```

Comment: what if multiple completable-futures throw exception; In such a case what exception would the future returned by `allOf` hold ? .Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Seems like it's the first one in the order you've passed them in the call to `allOf`, not the one raised the earliest.

Comment: What I'm unsure about here is, which method to use when; for example I could also chain the future returned by `allOf` with `handle`, `whenComplete`, `exceptionally`. The return type doesnt matter, as `allOf` returns a void and I still have to iterate futures passed to `allOf` for collecting individual results.

Comment: @V1666 The three methods you've listed there do *not* do the very same thing. There are subtle differences. I suggest checking out the javadocs of each...